# Can I create a collection of properties nodes and refer to them as a whole?

Tags: msbuild

I know I can do the following

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <Foo>Bar</Foo>
    <Foo1>Bar1</Foo1>
    <Foos>$(Foo) $(foo1)</Foos>
</PropertyGroup>

<Target Name="Def">
    <Message Text="$(Foos)"/>
</Target>
```

and get `Bar Bar1`

But this doesn't scale very well if you have many properties in the PropertyGroup.

Is there any way to reference a PropertyGroup or some other node and have MSBuild do the hard work for you?

I know the PropertyGroup element doesn't support it but imagine being able to do

```
<PropertyGroup Name="Bob">
    <Foo>Bar</Foo>
    <Foo1>Bar 1</Foo1>
</PropertyGroup>

<Target Name="Def">
    <Message Text="$(Bob)"/>
</Target>
```

and get `Bar Bar 1`

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using an ItemGroup and `@()` notation.

Example

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Foo Include="Bar"/>
    <Foo Include="Bar1"/>
</ItemGroup>

<Message Text="@(Foo)"/>
```

prints `Bar;Bar1`

notice the `@` symbol joins the items wt a semicolon by default. We can change this with a second paramter to `@(..)`.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Foo Include="Bar"/>
    <Foo Include="Bar1"/>
</ItemGroup>

<Message Text="@(Foo, ' ')"/>
```

prints `Bar Bar1`